# Has the Stack Exchange family led to first mention of any ideas publishable in peer-reviewed journals?

Tags: discussion, publicity

The Stack Exchange family of sites brings a lot of innovation and polish to the question-and-answer genre on the Internet.  The sites are attracting true subject-matter experts to a dialog that also brings in a multitude of questions from non-experts, representing both practical ideas and [disruptive innovation](http://blogs.hbr.org/innovation/flatmm/disruptive-ideas.pdf).

To what extent has the Stack Exchange family spawned new publishable lines of research?

For example, it appears that [an answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3133/mysql-old-password-cryptanalysis/3139#3139) by [Thomas Pornin](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/655/thomas-pornin) to my [MySQL OLD_PASSWORD cryptanalysis? - IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3133/mysql-old-password-cryptanalysis) question is the first cryptographic break of a very popular password hashing scheme.  *(Update: we found a previous publication.  But still - very cool)*

What other notable answers are out there, that might serve as good publicity for Stack Exchange in academic circles?

Comment: Some of Eric Lippert's answers on StackOverflow come to mind.

Comment: [Shameless self-promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3684484/77595), but I have high hopes this will end up getting published :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't cite any specific examples, but the two places I'd look are [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) (SE 1.0) and [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).  Both sites welcome only research level questions in their respective fields.

Comment: for MathOverflow see http://meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/64/where-to-keep-track-of-math-overflow-success-stories/

Answer (score 3):

I expect that the answer to my question here will be published, probably this year:
[Given two basis sets for a finite Hilbert space, does an unbiased vector exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28413/given-two-basis-sets-for-a-finite-hilbert-space-does-an-unbiased-vector-exist)

Comment: Do you mean that one of the arxiv citations given will be published in a peer-reviewed venue? (I don't think that counts.) Or that the actual answer will be published?

Comment: I mean "accepted for publication in a peer reviewed venue", but this means it would likely be in print in the next year. And by "this year" I mean "over the next 12 months". My "peer reviewed paper" count is only three, but I've only been doing it for the last couple years.